# OutputCache behaving strangely

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, caching

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();}
```

If, after I compiled this newly created application, browser B1 is
first to request  Cache.aspx, then the time displayed on received page
is 10.16:20.
If, after say 10 seconds, I refresh B1’s Cache.aspx( by clicking a
button to cause  a postback), then time 10.16.30 will show up, and on
all subsequent postbacks 10.16.30 will always be displayed ( until 1
hour elapses ).
If few minutes after B1 first requested Cache.aspx, browser B2 also
requests the same page, then upon receiving the page for the first
time, B2’s Cache.aspx will  display time 10.16.20, and on all
subsequent B2’s postbacks time 10.16:30 will be displayed instead.

A) So it appears that Asp.net generates two cached versions of
Cache.aspx ( thus code is executed twice ), one cached page is given
to browsers that request Cache.aspx for the first time, and second
cached page is given to browsers which only refresh their Cache.aspx?

B) Since my book never mentioned such a behavior, I’m wondering if you
get the same behavior  or is my Net environment again “unique”?

C) Creating two copies of same page ( thus executing the code twice )
seems like a waste of time, so why does Asp.Net operate like that –
there must be some reasoning/benefits behind it?

thank you

Comment: Are you sure all URLs involved are identical even down to the character casing?

Comment: ASP.NET does indeed generate different markups for different browsers. I'm not sure if it affects the <%@ OutputCache VaryByParam="none" %> or not.

Comment: >Are you sure all URLs involved are identical even down to the character casing?

Yes, since I copied URL from one browser to another 

>ASP.NET does indeed generate different markups for different browsers...

Not sure I understand what you're saying, but I used firefox in all my testings

Answer (score 2):

A complete guess, but presumably the cache is isolated by the overall request (query string args, etc)... even though the "none" turns off the key/value pairs, presumably a "GET" is simply still counted as different to a "POST"???

Try using simple links (`<a href...>` etc) rather than ASP.NET buttons.

Answer (score 0):

if i try 
if (ispostback)
begin
     response.cache.setcachebility(nocache)
end

then the button click updates the label every time.